# Disk/File modes of encryption and authentication

Tags: data-privacy

Secure disk/file encryption has been actively studied over the years. Beside XTS and CBC-ESSIV, are there any other modes of encryption that are commonly used? Which could be the most secure mode?

Due to the non-existence of integrity and authentication mechanisms, what are good methods to prevent a malicious person from modifying the data?

I am looking for a practical scheme that meets security and does not significantly impact performance.

Comment: Please note that your question(s!) are quite broad, as there are quite a few schemes used in practice. This holds even more if you want a discussion of the security properties of the modes. Especially your last question is quite broad. You could try to narrow the scope by defining "secure" (against whom with what capabilities?) and by specifying whether you want a pick from the commonly used modes or from the theoretically proposed ones for the second question. Also please specify whether you'd be willing to "waste" performance and storage to authentication.

Comment: Disk encryption and file encryption differ a lot in practice. The latter can use basically anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Beside XTS and CBC-ESSIV, are there any other modes of encryption that
>   are commonly used?

No. Just look at software like Veracrypt (XTS only) or dmcrypt.

There was a third notable scheme for this purpose, LRW, but it's deemed not secure enough:

> The issues of LRW were:
>
> a) An attacker can derive the LRW tweak key K2
>   from the ciphertext if the plaintext contains K2||0n or 0n||K2. Here
>   || is the concatenation operator and 0n is a zero block.[3] This may
>   be an issue for software that encrypts the partition of an operating
>   system under which this encryption software is running (at the same
>   time). The operating system could write the LRW tweak key to an
>   encrypted swap/hibernation file.
>
> b) If the tweak key K2 is known, LRW
>   does not offer indistinguishability under chosen plaintext attack
>   (IND-CPA) anymore, and the same input block permutation attacks of ECB
>   mode are possible.[4] Leak of the tweak key does not affect the
>   confidentiality of the plaintext.

(from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_P1619#LRW_issue)

> Which could be the most secure mode?

Depends on your requirements.

Both modes:
If the attacker can monitor changes of the data made by you (sounds like the attacker stole your computer, added something between harddisk and mainboard and gave it back), or at least get multiple copies at different point of times:
The attacker can do some traffic analysis, eg. he/she can detect if some block changed back to some data it had in the past. Ie. if you have a block has A, you change it to B, and later back to A (the same block, not different ones), then the attacker knows that the current content was there in the past too.
There's no real protection against this, but as said above, the attacker needs to monitor changes. Just stealing the laptop or anything like that is not enough (and if you get it back, don't trust it anymore, as simple as that. There are thousands of things that could be done while you weren't watching, many of them worse than just sniffing encrypted content).

XTS:
An attacker with similar monitoring capabilites, and also the possibility of changing blocks too, can roll back changes.
With the same A-B-A as above, (of course) the attacker can change your A block back to the B it was before (without knowing the unencrypted content, but still).
Just as reminder, overwriting the ciphertext is always possible, resulting in garbage after decryption. But here, it's not garbage, it's your own outdated content.
Tree-like integrity/authentication schemes (see below) mitigate this, but to be acceptable fast it needs to be integrated in the file system.

CBC-ESSIV:
It's always possible to change specific bits in the plaintext (even without monitoring changes or anything), if the attacker is willing to destroy another block for each changed block (=half of the blocks).
Again, tree-like integrity/authentication schemes mitigate this.

...if you want my opinion, XTS+auth.

> what are good methods to prevent a malicious person from modifying the
>   data?

What you should NOT do:
Take every 4096byte-block (or some size like that), use eg. 4076 byte for data and 20 for an HMAC. Because
a) it doesn't solve parts of the problems above (eg. for XTS, replacing a block with it's old content means the old HMAC is there too ... failed); and
b) it's a mismatch with what OS+programs usually want. If the OS reads 8192 bytes (2*4096), you need a third block because the first two contain 40 byte HMACs and just 8152 byte data. A 4096 block for 40 byte... Then, when the OS wants the next part of the file, you either need to read the same block again (even slower, because non-sequential) or implement some sort of caching, which gets very cumbersome.

What you should NOT do either:
Collect the HMACs in own blocks. 4096/20 is about 204, so each 204 data blocks are followed by one block full of HMACs.
a) This does not solve the replacement problem either (the attacker can just replace a chunk of 205 blocks), and
b) It's even slower, because for every block you read/write, you also need the hash block which is far away (non-sequential to it's best).

What you could do on block-only-level (more secure but still slow):
Start like the solution above (full hash blocks), but also insert a second level of hash blocks (err, MAC blocks) for each eg. 200 hash blocks, a third level for each 200 second-levels, and so on, until you have one top block.
With this, replacing single blocks or any larger parts always can be detected, *unless* the attacker changes *everything*, ie. the whole disk content, back to it's old content etc. (this part can't really be solved with crypto. It's like exchanging the whole hard disk with one containing your old data. To mitigate this, you need to store the top block securely outside if the hard disk).
Problem is, again, slow because of non-sequential access. And calculating where the X-th data block is becomes a bit cumbersome because of the levels.

It won't get more secure. But depending on what you want to do, the slowness problem can be solved too: Don't do it just with blocks, without knowing their purpose, but integrate the hash tree into the file system.
There's no need to fetch additional blocks for the hashes, because they can be in the same place where filenames etc. are stored too. And knowing what blocks belong to the same file, detecting the programs access patterns for proper caching, etc.etc., all can be applied to the hash part too.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining, I got your points :) I have been reading up on the variations of Merkle hash tree and it seems like a good way to provide authentication. However, with added security, the computational performance is impacted and storage might also be another issue. Well, a trade-off between these :)